# Systemd service not restarting as expected

Tags: linux, services, systemd

all the files referenced below can be seen here
https://github.com/sm0svx/svxlink/tree/master/src/svxlink/systemd

Question:

*Caveat - I am a hardware engineer with some reasonable scripting capability, I don't mind digging into something, but I just don't have a wealth of OS type experience so I may ask some seemingly noob questions, please forgive these questions as a noob trying to learn and understand.*

I am running up against a systemd issue that is beyond my understanding although I expect it is fairly simple for those of you more versed.

```
    [Unit]
Description=SvxLink repeater control software GPIO setup
Documentation=man:svxlink(1)

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=@SBIN_INSTALL_DIR@/svxlink_gpio_up
ExecStop=@SBIN_INSTALL_DIR@/svxlink_gpio_down

#Restart=on-failure
TimeoutStartSec=60
WorkingDirectory=@SVX_SYSCONF_INSTALL_DIR@
RemainAfterExit=True

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

What the code does right, is at boot time the svxlink_gpio_up script is called and everything gets setup correctly.  When I manually run the svxlink_gpio_down script it also runs correctly.

What I am running into though is when I want to restart this service, the gpio is not torn down and rebuilt so I have to reboot the device to get to reconfigure the gpio as expected.

What I am thinking I need to add is the following to the [Service] section.  My concern is first, is this the correct approach, and second, will there be any type of race conditions that I need to understand and contend with.

A potentially related question, is the Type=OneShot appropriate?  I am thinking this should instead be Type=simple as to me a OneShot is just that, something that can only be run one time.

ExecReload=@SBIN_INSTALL_DIR@/svxlink_gpio_down;@SBIN_INSTALL_DIR@/svxlink_gpio_up

```
    or 

    ExecReload=@SBIN_INSTALL_DIR@/svxlink_gpio_down
    ExecReload=@SBIN_INSTALL_DIR@/svxlink_gpio_up
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

OCT 27 2019 - Adding additional information based on Grawity's feedback

the `systemctl stop svxlink` task does not actually succeed completely as the gpio are not torn down as expected.

```
pi-star@pi-repeater-mmdvm(ro):~$ ls /sys/class/gpio/gpio
gpio472/     gpio475/     gpiochip0/   gpiochip464/ gpiochip496/
gpio474/     gpio478/     gpiochip100/ gpiochip480/ gpiochip504/
```

I don't see anything wrong with the status of the service when I interrogate it after stopping it

```
● svxlink.service - SvxLink repeater control software
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/svxlink.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Sun 2019-10-27 19:22:58 PDT; 1min 48s ago
     Docs: man:svxlink(1)
  Process: 1085 ExecStartPre=/bin/touch ${LOGFILE} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1098 ExecStartPre=/bin/chown ${RUNASUSER} ${LOGFILE} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1100 ExecStart=/usr/bin/svxlink --logfile=${LOGFILE} --config=${CFGFILE} --pidfile=${PIDFILE} --runasuser
 Main PID: 1100 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Oct 27 19:22:58 pi-repeater-mmdvm systemd[1]: Stopping SvxLink repeater control software...
Oct 27 19:22:58 pi-repeater-mmdvm systemd[1]: svxlink.service: Succeeded.
Oct 27 19:22:58 pi-repeater-mmdvm systemd[1]: Stopped SvxLink repeater control software.
Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
```

I also have checked the svxlink logs with no signs of error

```
Sun Oct 27 19:22:58 2019: SIGTERM received. Shutting down application...
```

When I call the _down task directly everything tears down as expected

```
pi-star@pi-repeater-mmdvm(ro):~$ /usr/sbin/svxlink_gpio_down
pi-star@pi-repeater-mmdvm(ro):~$ ls /sys/class/gpio/
export       gpiochip0/   gpiochip100/ gpiochip464/ gpiochip480/ gpiochip496/ gpiochip504/ unexport
```

I also tried to start the svxlink application again and the gpio again were not configured

```
pi-star@pi-repeater-mmdvm(ro):~$ sudo systemctl start svxlink.service
pi-star@pi-repeater-mmdvm(ro):~$ ls /sys/class/gpio/gpiochip
gpiochip0/   gpiochip100/ gpiochip464/ gpiochip480/ gpiochip496/ gpiochip504/
pi-star@pi-repeater-mmdvm(ro):~$ ls /sys/class/gpio/gpiochip
```

Answer (score 0):

> What the code does right, is at boot time the svxlink_gpio_up script is called and everything gets setup correctly. When I manually run the svxlink_gpio_down script it also runs correctly.
>
> What I am running into though is when I want to restart this service, the gpio is not torn down and rebuilt so I have to reboot the device to get to reconfigure the gpio as expected.

Investigate *exactly which part* of the process fails. It could be failing during the _down script, or during the _up script, or somewhere in between.

Make sure your service actually shows up as "active" in `systemctl status` after boot (i.e. it hasn't failed, and your RemainOnExit setting is being honored too).

When you use `systemctl restart` on a Type=oneshot service, that is mostly equivalent to `systemctl stop` followed by immediate `systemctl start`. In order for the 'stop' job to work, the service actually has to be in 'active' state.

Try to make sure the scripts themselves can cope with any situation – i.e. the _down script should always work without errors even if some or all GPIOs have already been torn down previously, and same for the _up script. They can show something like a *warning* but not die with an error.

> What I am thinking I need to add is the following to the [Service] section. My concern is first, is this the correct approach, and second, will there be any type of race conditions that I need to understand and contend with.

This would work if you wanted to use `systemctl reload`, but is somewhat redundant as it does exactly the same thing as a restart would.

(Usually `systemctl reload` is meant for applying configuration in a way that doesn't need to completely tear down the existing configuration.)

> A potentially related question, is the Type=OneShot appropriate? I am thinking this should instead be Type=simple as to me a OneShot is just that, something that can only be run one time.

`Type=oneshot` is a service unit with no long-lived processes. The service is marked as "started" after all of its ExecStart processes run to completion.

`Type=simple` is a service unit with one main process. The service is marked as "started" as soon as its (one) ExecStart process *begins*, and is marked as "stopped" when that process exits.

Comment: I edited the post to include the additional testing steps that I have looked into based on your guidance.  I am not sure how to localize it down further from here